# What's the difference between django_extension.db and django.db？

Tags: django, django-models, django-extensions

I want to generate UUID for my models, and officially, what I did is exactly as what the official doc demonstrates.

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class MyUUIDModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

However, I also find `django_extension` to do similiar job for me. I don't know what's the difference between, but I do want to unify my code for better production purpose. Any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django did not include a `UUIDField` until version 1.8, which is why it was created as an "extension" by the Django Extensions maintainers. Now that Django includes `UUIDField` natively the Django Extensions maintainers are sunsetting their version, but are continuing to maintain their `UUIDField` for people using Django < 1.8 until Django 1.7 is no longer supported [per the docs](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/field_extensions.html).

If you are using Django >= 1.8 you should be using `django.db.models.UUIDField`.